# How do I turn on or off a led from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, raspberry-pi

I am trying to see the status of the LEDs connected to the raspberry, and by means of XMLHTTPRequest requests I manage to get the status of the LEDs and if they are on, a circle is green and if they are off in red. I am using the raspberry as a server where I have this code working:

```
var express = require('express');
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('.'));

var outs = [new Gpio(17, 'out'), new Gpio(18, 'out'), new Gpio(27, 'out'), new $
var ins = [new Gpio(24, 'in', 'both')];

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PAT$
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-typ$
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
 });

app.get('/out/:id/:state', function (request, response) {
  let id = request.params.id;
  let state = request.params.state;
  //console.log('id: ' +  id);
  //console.log('state: ' + state);
  if ('read' == state) {
    let value = outs[id].readSync();
    response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(value));
} else {
    outs[id].writeSync(parseInt(state));
    response.sendStatus(200).end();
}
});

app.get('/blink/:id/:delay/:count', function (request, response) {
  let id = parseInt(request.params.id);
  let delay = parseInt(request.params.delay);
  let count = parseInt(request.params.count);

  let i = 0;
  let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    if (i++ >= count) clearInterval(intervalId);
    outs[id].writeSync(outs[id].readSync() ? 0 : 1);
}, delay);
response.sendStatus(200).end();
});

app.get('/in/:id', function (request, response) {
  let id = parseInt(request.params.id);
  let value = ins[id].readSync();
  response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(value));
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at htpp://%s:%s", host, port)
})

module.exports = app;
```

And this is my HTML code that takes the information from the server and reads it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>GPIO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/GPIO.css">
<h1>GPIO</h1>

</head>

<body>

<div class="split left">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Inputs</h3>
        <p>ID</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Outputs</h3>

        <table>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Change</th>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="redondo0" class="button"> </div><br>
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick=cambio()>Switch</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="redondo1" class="button"></div><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="redondo2" class="button"></div><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="redondo3" class="button"></div><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>

setInterval(function () {

    let request0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request0.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        if (request0.readyState == 4) {
            if (request0.status == 200) {

                var data = (request0.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                var boton = document.querySelector("#redondo0");
                if (request0.responseText == 0) {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "#ABFF00";
                } else {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    })
    request0.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/0/read");
    request0.send();


    let request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request1.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        if (request1.readyState == 4) {
            if (request1.status == 200) {

                var data = (request1.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                var boton = document.querySelector("#redondo1");
                if (request1.responseText == 0) {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "#ABFF00";
                } else {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    })
    request1.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/1/read");
    request1.send();


    let request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request2.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        if (request2.readyState == 4) {
            if (request2.status == 200) {

                var data = (request2.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                var boton = document.querySelector("#redondo2");
                if (request2.responseText == 0) {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "#ABFF00";
                } else {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    })
    request2.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/2/read");
    request2.send();


    let request3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request3.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        if (request3.readyState == 4) {
            if (request3.status == 200) {

                var data = (request3.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                var boton = document.querySelector("#redondo3");
                if (request3.responseText == 0) {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "#ABFF00";
                } else {
                    boton.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    })
    request3.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/3/read");
    request3.send();

}, 1 * 1000);

function cambio() {
    let request4 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request4.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        if (request4.readyState == 4) {
            if (request4.status == 200) {

                var data = (request4.responseText);
                console.log(data);

                if (request4.responseText == 0) {
                    request4.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/0/1");
                    request4.send();
                } else {
                    request4.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.135:8081/out/0/0");
                    request4.send();
                }
            }
        }
    })
}



</script>

</html>
```

What I want is through the button that turns the assigned led on or off, do you have any idea how to do it? I have tried to do it by XMLHTTPRequest request but I can't, thanks for the help.

Comment: This seems to be just a matter of requesting the correct URL, everything else seems to be in place already. Is this about running a request when a button is clicked? Your first button attempts to call `cambio()` but you don't seem to have that function. Also note that you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of the long winded XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had deleted the "change" function because it didn't work and I don't know how to do it now, could you help me? And the fetch thing thanks but I don't know very well how to use it so I'll look at it, thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67769412/edit) your question and add the code you've tried.

Comment: Yes of course. Do not judge me for how bad I have done it, I have recently started with javascript and I do not know how to do many things hahahaha. But I would appreciate if you could tell me how to do it correctly and tell me what is wrong. Thanks. I just updated it.

Comment: Here's how to do this without XMLHttpRequest and duplicate code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/s9pLxe6n/

Comment: Note that a better solution in the long run is to use [sockets](https://socket.io/) to update the state of each button from the server. That way you don't have to run X requests per second that don't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for everything, but could you also help me to do it with XMLHTTPRequest? I would like to know since I am with the requests how to do it, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry, why? Why not learn how to use fetch, given that it is widely supported by browsers? Also, do you really need me to convert my code back to use XMLHttpRequest? Seems like a good exercise to do it yourself ;)